# Xcode closure auto completion issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

The following is working code built against iOS 8.4 using Xcode 6.4

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: { response, data, error in
    if error != nil {
        println("there be an error")
    } else {
        let image = UIImage(data:data)
        self.webimage.image = image
    }
})
```

If I double click the closure section of the method signature as Xcode auto completes it I end up in this state:

[image]

Xcode has not put `})` at the end of the closure and also added `-> Void in`.

Is this a bug in Xcode 6.4 or are there two alternate syntaxes for closures?

When would I need `completionHandler : { arg, arg arg in` versus `completionHandler : {(arg,arg,arg) -> Void in //code })`

Comment: Would this be a helpful start, if it could be customized to your needs somehow? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932152/xcode-auto-complete-for-blocks-within-a-block-and-the-blocks-theyre-in

Answer (score 5):

The way that Xcode autocomplete your instruction is in the "trailing closures style."

From the Apple documentation:

> If you need to pass a closure expression to a function as the
>   function’s final argument and the closure expression is long, it can
>   be useful to write it as a trailing closure instead. A trailing
>   closure is a closure expression that is written outside of (and after)
>   the parentheses of the function call it supports

If you want to know more about the trailing closure, please report to the doc here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html  (cf section Trailing Closures)